# row number and distinct together

Tags: mysql

Given table "table1"

```
name
------
Jhon
Jhon
Robert
Robert
Robert
```

Needed get unique names and also numeric names as queue,
that is result bust be:

```
1  Jhon
2  Robert
```

this query not works

```
SET @n = 0;

SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS n,  DISTINCT  name FROM table1
```

I dont ask how to make this, (this may be make with sub-querys right?) , my question is: why dont working query, which I writed upstairs? why dont like mysql this query?

Comment: You are not ordering by anything, so row ranks won't really be of any significant use; a subsequent query might return the names in a completely different order, and the numbers will not correspond to the previous set of numbers.  If you need to number rows in the output for usability, then consider adding those numbers in the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why MySQL doesn't like this query:

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS n,  DISTINCT  name FROM table1
```

This query is not correct because SQL's `DISTINCT` query modifier applies to the whole row, not just to a single column or subset of columns.  This is a common misunderstanding made by SQL programmers.

In other words, the result is reduced by `DISTINCT` only if *all* columns are the same as another row.

Syntactically, the `DISTINCT` keyword must follow `SELECT`. It's not correct to put it after other columns.

You could write the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT @n := @n + 1 AS n, name FROM table1
```

But this query wouldn't get you what you wanted.  It would apply the incrementing variable to *every* row of table1, and then apply `DISTINCT` to the whole result.  Since every row is guaranteed to have a distinct value `n`, the `DISTINCT` would have no effect.

Other answers have described doing the `DISTINCT` inside a derived table (subquery), so that it forces the rows to be reduced based only on the distinct values of `name`, and then apply the incrementing variable to the resulting rows.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_number,
       table1.name
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT name
        FROM   sparkles) table1
       JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Will produce:

```
| ROW_NUMBER |   NAME |
-----------------------
|          1 |   John |
|          2 | Robert |
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31a4a/1)

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear what you are asking but, do you mean something like this:

```
select name, @rn:=@rn+1 n
from
(
  select distinct name
  from table1
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
order by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5fb6/3)

Results:

```
|   NAME | N |
--------------
|   Jhon | 1 |
| Robert | 2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had same kind of problem when i explored that there is no such function like `Row Number()` as it is in MS SQL then i tried following trick and it worked for me

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 AS n,  name from (select DISTINCT  name FROM table1) tb;
```